# Contour integration for inverse cosine

Tags: contour-integration

I wanna calculate the integral 
$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm d q \frac{1}{\cos ka -\cos qa}.$$
I think this problem can be solved by using the contour integration, but I don't really have a good idea on how to manipulate the integrand. 
Any comment would be appreciated!

Comment: The integrand has infinitely many non-integrable singularities, and does not decay at all as $q \to \infty$ because it is periodic.  The only sensible answer is "undefined".

Comment: What if I want to calculate the principal value of this integral? Can I obtain a finite value?

Comment: For any finite $R$, the principal value of the integral for $0$ to $R$ will exist.  The limit of that as $R \to \infty$ will not exist.